# In Bash, how can I compute and capture the result from an intermediate node in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, pipe

In Bash, how can I compute and capture the result from an intermediate node in a pipeline?

For example, given a list of integers and a command or function `maximum`, using a single Bash pipeline, how can I capture the maximum value of the list of integers in a variable, but also output the list to standard output?

In the following Bash script, the idea is to change function `capture_maximum_and_print_numbers` so that it is a single pipeline.

```
function maximum {
  awk 'NR==1||$0>x{x=$0}END{print x}'
}

function capture_maximum_and_print_numbers {
  local numbers="3\n6\n1\n4\n2\n9\n5\n"
  maximum=$(printf $numbers | maximum)
  printf $numbers
}

capture_maximum_and_print_numbers
printf "maximum=$maximum\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are strictly looking to both assign the result to a variable AND output the list of numbers to standard output in a single line then the following will give you what you want (I changed the name of your maximum function to correspond to what it does, with the variable `$maximum` corresponding to the stored result itself):

```bsh
function calc_max {
  awk 'NR==1||$0>x{x=$0}END{print x}'
}

function capture_maximum_and_print_numbers {
  local numbers="3\n6\n1\n4\n2\n9\n5\n"
  export maximum=$(printf $numbers | tee /dev/tty | calc_max)
 

}

capture_maximum_and_print_numbers 
echo max_result="$maximum"
#You have stored the max_result variable and can pass it to whatever you want.
```

`tee` can be used in the middle of long command piping to store the "current" result in different files, output to stdout etc. It splits the single pipe into multiple copies with individual destinations, while still allowing your "primary" pipe to process further down the chain.

`tee dev/tty` corresponds to piping to the current `tty` terminal and `/dev/tty` will be present on every *nix system

Comment: Is it possible to use `tee` to store the result directly into a shell variable in the same context in which it is run?

Comment: Why do you `export` the `maximum` variable? By sending the output to `/dev/tty`, you make it impossible (or very difficult) to redirect the output of this script to e.g. a file or some other processing step.  It also requires a TTY, which would _not_ be available if the script was run in a non-interactive session (e.g. via a cron job).

Comment: Exporting the variable was done to fulfill the capturing requirement of  "how can I capture the maximum value of the list of integers in a variable, but also output the list to standard output?". The good thing about specifying `export` for the result variable is it allows you to "pull it out" into your current shell using `source [script]` or `. [script]` if needed. Also, you are absolutely right that `/dev/tty` would not work for cron jobs, but  cron's stdout needs redirection to file by default or it goes to mail. Also, any cron job can be ran without it inside of a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

generate_data () {
        shuf -i 0-1000 -n 10 -r
}

print_maximum () {
        awk 'NR == 1 || m < $0 { m = $0 } END { print m }'
}

exec 3>&1
maximum=$(
    generate_data |
    tee /dev/fd/3 |
    print_maximum
)
exec 3>&-

printf 'maximum = %d\n' "$maximum"
```

This passes some random numbers through `tee`, duplicating them to  file descriptor 3 and to the standard output of `tee`.  The standard output is read by `print_maximum`, which finds and outputs the largest number among the ones generated.

File descriptor 3 is initially opened as copy of the shell's standard output stream (with `exec 3>&1`), which means that when `tee` writes to it (by writing to `/dev/fd/3`), the data appears on the shell's standard output.  That file descriptor is later closed (with `exec 3>&-`).

Note that the script uses `/bin/sh` as it does not need to use any bash-isms.  With `bash` though, you'd be guaranteed that `/dev/fd/3` was usable as file descriptor 3, and not reliant on that path being provided by the system.

Example run:

```
$ sh script
918
787
290
998
737
1000
845
374
497
809
maximum = 1000
```

To show that all output is generated on the script's standard output, I can show that it's possible to `grep` the generated data:

```
$ sh script | grep -F 0
100
807
maximum = 807
```

```
$ sh script | grep -F 0
440
207
```

Comment: If file descriptor 3 is a copy of standard output, why doesn't `tee /dev/fd/3` output the input data twice to standard output, once to `/dev/fd/3` and then to standard output attached to file descriptor 1?

Comment: I think I understand why there is no duplication.  You copy standard output to file descriptor 3 in the parent shell and `tee /dev/fd/3` writes to standard output in the child shell.  Two different standard outputs!